# Why is form causing visibility of image to change?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, visibility

I have a very simple form:

```html
<form>
   <input type="text" onchange="togglePic()">  
   <img src="img/family.JPG" id="pictest">
</form>
```

I then have the following script:

```js
function togglePic() {

 var imageOBJ = document.getElementById("pictest");

 if (imageOBJ.style.visibility == "hidden")
  imageOBJ.style.visibility = "visible";
 else
  imageOBJ.style.visibility = "hidden";

}
```

When I execute, the picture disappears and always reappears. While the code executes properly, it seems to reset the image's visibility to "" rather than holding onto the hidden or visible setting. 
If I remove form tag, the code works properly.

I am not seeking another way to accomplish this (as I know there are several options). I am just trying to understand why the form tag impedes the setting of the visibility attribute.

Comment: it is holding `visible/hidden` when I test it  http://jsbin.com/xehedik/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I agree. It works here but I promise when I create a stand-alone web page it does not run with Chrome or Firefox. The debugger hides/shows image but after completing function, image always returns. I feel like it has something to do with a form reset or refresh that may be taken place.